# How to make the page to work with signOut even after refresh

Tags: javascript, angular

I have home page, in which i have signin and signout column. 
I have user page, in which one more signUp form is there.
Now, if i signOut, it works fine but once i refresh the page, it works as still the user is not signOut.
Can anyone help me to solve my issue.

**HTML of User page:**

```
<ul>
<li class="signUp" *ngIf = "loggedIn">{{userName}}</li>
<li class="signIn" (click)="signOut()" *ngIf = "loggedIn">Sign Out</li>
<li class="signUp" (click)="openSignUp(user)"  *ngIf = "!loggedIn">Sign Up</li>
<li class="signIn" (click)="openSignIn(logedin)"  *ngIf = "!loggedIn">Sign In</li>
</ul>
```

**TS:**

```
**In service:** 



 private signOutSource = new Subject<any>(); 
    signoutDone$ = this.signOutSource.asObservable(); 

signOut() { 
this.signOutSource.next(); 
}
```

**home.ts:**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnDestroy { 
constructor(private ApiService:ApiService) { 
this.subscription = ApiService.signinDone$.subscribe( 
user => { 
this.userName = user.name; 
localStorage.setItem('loggedin', 'true'); 
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user)); 
this.loggedIn = true; 
this.isLoadingSignUp = false; 
this.ApiService.getUserData(user); 
}); 
if(localStorage.getItem('loggedin')){ 
this.loggedIn = true; 
} else { 
this.loggedIn = false; 
} 
if(localStorage.getItem('user')){ 
this.userName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).name; 
} 
this.logoutSubscription = ApiService.signoutDone$.subscribe( 
user => { 
localStorage.setItem('loggedin', 'false'); 
this.loggedIn = false; 
this.ApiService.getUserData({}); 
}); 
} 

ngOnDestroy() { 
this.subscription.unsubscribe(); 
} 

signOut() { 
this.ApiService 
.logout() 
.subscribe( 
user => { 
localStorage.removeItem('user'); 
localStorage.removeItem('loggedin'); 
this.ApiService.getUserData({}); 
this.loggedIn = false; 
this.router.navigate(['/home']); 
this.toasterService.pop('success', 'SignOut Successfull'); 
this.ApiService.signOut(); 
},error => { 
if(error.data && error.data.length > 0) { 
this.toasterService.pop('error', error.data); 
} else { 
this.toasterService.pop('error', 'Something went wrong!'); 
} 
}); 
} 

}
```

**User.componet:**

```
export class UserComponent implements OnDestroy { 
constructor(private ApiService:ApiService) { 
this.subscription = ApiService.signinDone$.subscribe( 
user => { 
this.userName = user.name; 
localStorage.setItem('loggedin', 'true'); 
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user)); 
this.loggedIn = true; 
this.isLoadingSignUp = false; 
this.ApiService.getUserData(user); 
}); 
if(localStorage.getItem('loggedin')){ 
this.loggedIn = true; 
} else { 
this.loggedIn = false; 
} 
if(localStorage.getItem('user')){ 
this.userName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).name; 
} 
this.logoutSubscription = ApiService.signoutDone$.subscribe( 
user => { 
localStorage.setItem('loggedin', 'false'); 
this.loggedIn = false; 
this.ApiService.getUserData({}); 
}); 
} 

ngOnDestroy() { 
this.subscription.unsubscribe(); 
} 

}
```

**HTML of user Page:**

```
 <div class="favourate" *ngIf="!loggedIn">
    <h1>User</h1>
    <hr />
    <div class="backImage">
      <form name="signUpForm" class="signUpForm" #signUpForm="ngForm" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
          <h3>Sign Up</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group input">
          <mat-form-field> 
            <mat-icon>perm_identity</mat-icon>
            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="name" #Name="ngModel" required>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group input">
          <mat-form-field> 
            <mat-icon>email</mat-icon>
            <input matInput type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="user.email" #Email="ngModel" pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$" required>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group input">
          <mat-form-field> 
            <mat-icon>lock</mat-icon>
            <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" #Password="ngModel" required>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>          
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: why do u want signin and signout on both the pages just place it on home page after login show home page only. is there any special criterial to do so?

Comment: initially, il have SignIn and SignUp, so from user page, SignUp form also will be there. Once i login with SignIn or SignUp, then SignUp form from user page hides, when i SignOut, i need all these SignIn and SignUp, so from user page, SignUp form to come

Comment: i didn't find any sense having 2 signIn and SignOut form in same app

Comment: Once i SignIn, the word SignIn gets replaced with signOut

Comment: do u get any error? have check what value resided at your `loggedIn` variable?

Comment: i dont get any error, and loggedIn will be false when i do signout

Comment: what do u exactly mean by "the user page contents are not shown."

Comment: i will edit full question because half of the output i got

Comment: YEAH actually its needed because your question is not clearly understood yet u dont have submit button and where your signout method get calls didit get any link of your code

Comment: i had edited my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are storing `loggedIn` details in `local storage`, 
Just add `localstorage` check in `ngOnOnit`.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy { 

    ngOnInit() { 
        if(localStorage.getItem('loggedin')){ 
            if(localStorage.getItem('loggedin') == 'true') 
            { 
                this.loggedIn = true; 
            } 
            else
            { 
                this.loggedIn = false; 
            } 
        }else{
            this.loggedIn = false; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much